Four numbers with unique representations for 1-10 with simpler operands
For four values and basic operands, there are 1170 inequivalent expressions (A140606). For example, $a+b$ and $b+a$ are equivalent. While testing my code for this, I came across the following:
$\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & \{\text{(((13-11)$\times $9)-17)}\} \\
 2 & \{\text{(17-(11+(13-9)))},\text{((17-13)$\div $(11-9))}\} \\
 3 & \{\text{((11+13)$\div $(17-9))}\} \\
 4 & \{\text{((17-9)$\div $(13-11))}\} \\
 5 & \{\text{((11+9)$\div $(17-13))}\} \\
 6 & \{\text{(11+(17-(13+9)))}\} \\
 7 & \{\text{((11+17)$\div $(13-9))}\} \\
 8 & \{\text{((11-9)$\times $(17-13))}\} \\
 9 & \{\text{(((11-9)$\times $13)-17)},\text{(11-((17+9)$\div $13))}\} \\
 10 & \{\text{(17-(11-(13-9)))},\text{((17$\times $9)-(11$\times $13))}\} \\
\end{array}$
For the numbers (9,11,13,17), the goal numbers (1,3,4,5,6,7,8) have unique representations.
Is there a set of four numbers where all goal numbers 1 to 10 have unique representations? If so, what is the highest $n$ where all goal number 1 to $n$ have unique representations?

Dually, for any $n$, what is the largest number number $m$ such that all of ${1, \ldots, m}$ are uniquely representable in this way using some set of $n$ numbers? Trivially A140606 comprises upper bounds.

For $a = 3, b = 17, c = 23, d = 36$ I get
$$ \eqalign{ 1 &= 17 - 3 + 23 - 36\cr
             2 &= (36/3)/(23-17) \cr
             3 &= 36/(23-17)-3 \cr
             4 &= 36/(3 - 17 + 23)\cr
             5 &= (3 \times 36 - 23)/17\cr
             6 &= 17 - 23 + 36/3 \cr
             7 &= 3 + 17 + 23 - 36\cr
             8 &= 23 + 36 - 3 \times 17\cr
             9 &= 3 + 36/(23 - 17) \cr
            10 &= (17 - 23 + 36)/3 \cr}$$
and all unique, if my computations are correct.
[EDIT] It turns out that this does minimize $\max(a,b,c,d)$.

Is this example minimal (say, in the sense of minimizing $\operatorname{max}{a, b, c, d}$, perhaps requiring all numbers to be nonnegative integers)?

Probably not. I searched the combinations of $4$ positive integers from ${1, \ldots, 40}$, which Maple returns in lexicographic order.

Verified, all of these are unique.  Also, no solution for 11 and 2 solutions for 12, so this particular solution doesn't extend.
